# Block Chain Decryption

Tags: block-cipher

Given the encryption formula and flow chart for block-chaining. How could I make the decryption version of this? Would it just be everything in reverse?

[image: Block Chain Flow Chart]

Comment: It looks like [homework](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)..    what do you expect as a result? (a formula?) The CBC schema is nicely [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29 ) and indeed decryption is in most of the cases the reverse